# file download in ipad in web application asp.net

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net

I am downloading a file on button click in a web application using the code below but when I open my web app in iPad and click the download button the file opens up in the browser and I have no option to close it or do anything unless I press the back button, which takes me one step back in application.

Can you please help me out with this issue.

```
protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btnDownload = (LinkButton)sender;
        int file_id = Convert.ToInt32(btnDownload.Attributes["data-file-id"].ToString());
        AMformData = new Active_MonitorFormData();
        DataTable file = AMformData.getEvidenceFileById(file_id);
        if (file.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string filename = file.Rows[0]["file_name"].ToString().Replace(' ', '_');
            byte[] fileContent = file.Rows[0]["file_content"] as byte[];
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = file.Rows[0]["file_content_type"].ToString();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename + "");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileContent.Length.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(fileContent);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: iOS 12 doesn't 'do' downloading to the file system like a PC does. What kind of file is it? What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I want to display the file to the user on the click of the button be or allow them to save it if the want or just save the file directly so they can open it later. Is there any way to do this

Comment: files can be different types like images, pdf, word and excel files. when I click the button file opened like the image it is open but once it is open I am not able to find a way to close and move back to the button page

Comment: I make it work by opening image in a new tab it is not a proper solution but it is a workaround for now.